# Fixing Error of WordPress rss Feed

Tags: wordpress

I have this website http://www.example.co.id/feed/
can you help me to fix the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most commonly caused by a Blank line before XML declaration

you can see:

```
view-source:http://www.example.co.id/feed/
```

Comment: My client want to use SmartFTP in file uploading, I can't Access the file feed-rss2.php located in ../wp-includes/

Comment: I only allowed to access files under ../wp-content/.. Please help me. THank you

Comment: you need to check into files. may be some files have white space. Even you can see view-source:http://www.ligamahasiswa.co.id/. your root url have blank line

Comment: I dont know where to edit that xml file

Comment: not xml file, you need to check into php files

Comment: what is the file name of that php file?

Comment: you need to check one by one in php files. PHP files will have blank lines after the closing tag like in wp-config.php in root folder, feed.php in wp-includes ,functions.php into theme

Comment: might be issue with your functions.php file. pl enable theme to twentytwelve and check once. if works then issue is into functions.php file.

Comment: nothing happends :( i feel frustrated

Comment: Have you change theme to twentytwelve? Pl show me after activating default theme

Comment: not yet I need the theme twentythirteen its my client request :(

Comment: yes i understand, you just activate default theme once and check feed url so get some idea that issue is with theme or not then after revert back with your theme

Comment: how about the plugins? if I disable the theme?

Comment: after disabling theme, you just need to check http://www.ligamahasiswa.co.id/feed/ url and then re-enable theme

Comment: I already uploaded it in SmartFTP theres no other themes. only twentythirteen

Comment: could you upload twentytwelve theme?

Comment: but how it is happen that I can view the feed in safari?

Comment: I can't, I dont have access for the other files. The only files that I can access is files in the SmartFTP